Superset is missing MySQL after upgrade from 3.0.0 to 4.1.1
I have updated superset from 3.0.0 to 4.1.1 in my docker container.
I am currently using a flask to authenticate to AzureAD so my requirements-local.txt looks like this post upgrade:

psycopg2-binary
flask-cors
flask_openid
prophet
pystan
pymssql
pymysql

The issue I am running into is when I try to use any of the MySQL data connections I get the error:

    MySQL Error
    No module named 'MySQLdb'

The same error presents itself in Sql Lab
When I go to edit the database connection the 'Basic' tab is blank (see attached)
Looking at the logs a similar message is present but with a call stack

This turns out to be an issue with the docker image tagged 4.1.1.
I created a bug ticket here: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/31459


install mysql dependencies needed.
add two lines in "config.py":

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()


restart superset.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
